# Styling android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchIcon with correct size

Tags: android, layout, toolbar, android-appcompat, searchview

I have an app with a themen that extends Base.Theme.AppCompat and has the  com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3 in its dependencies. I'd like to switch the searchIcon of the android.support.v7.widget.SearchView wich I can do, however it is larger than the other items in the menu of the toolbar.

I included the item by adding a style for Widget.AppCompat.SearchView extending Base.Widget.AppCompat.SearchView to my style.xml which sets the searchIcon to my own drawable. The drawable is the same size as the drawables for the other action items.

I include the searchView in a Toolbar, also from appcompat.